# Can I load .gml in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphml

I saved a .gml from wolfram mathimatica, does anyone have an example of how to load the file and display on a webpage? I am dealing with d3 at the moment, would another language be more appropriate?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same question, have you resolved the problem or found any work-around?

Answer (score 0):

There's a really good [post](https://www.giacomodebidda.com/visualize-gml-files-with-d3/) on exactly this at one developer's blog.

The gist of it is that D3, even in its latest version (v4, at the time of writing this), can't import GML files. However, you can convert a GML file into a JSON file, which D3 can read. You can use [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) for this conversion.

Alternatively, you may use [Gephi](http://gephi.org/) to export the edges and nodes to CSV separately.